# Does the Windows 8 app works on iPad

Tags: windows-8

I'm developing a business application that needs to work on Windows 8 surface tablet. I am planning to use HTML5 CSS and Javascript for development.

My question is , will the same app for windows 8 ,works in iPad and/or android without any modifications ?

Thanks !

Comment: Not sure why i was downvoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a Windows 8 application won't work on iPad or an Android device without any modifications by default.  If you want to code native applications, you need to use Objective-C for iPad development and Java for Android development.

But, here are some options.

- You could have a modification of your Windows 8 app in HTML5 and JavaScript that runs in a web browser as a normal website in HTML5 and JavaScript.  But these would be two different codebases (one for Windows 8 and one for the web, both in HTML5 and JavaScript...main difference is that the Windows 8 app would probably call some WinRT APIs and other Windows 8 specific functionality).
- You could use tools/technologies like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) (which allows you to code in C# and export to a variety of app formats).